# How to get up to 24 I/O pins from the PIC4550

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, ethernet, crc

Im trying to implement  and understand the CRC by making a circuit, by using 1 byte (8 bits), and a highest power of the polynomial of four, these 2 values should be XORed until i get a final output, that should be 12 leds confirming the proper data was recieved

I was wiring my leds, in order to use the PIC4550 however Im not sure I have enough digital ports to do this, all the inputs and outputs should be shown in ledbars, thats 8 ports for the input, 4 ports for the polynomial, 12 for the output thats a total of 24 ports

[image]

[image]

Im already checking the datasheet, trying to find out mos of these questions, however i wanted to throw the question to confirm

1) If i cant do it with a 40pin DIP then what else can i use to make it work?

2) Is it posible to override the analog inputs and use them for this porpuse?

Comment: You can reduce the amount of required pins drastically by using [multiplexing](http://www.instructables.com/id/Multiplexing-with-Arduino-and-the-74HC595/step1/What-Is-Multiplexing/). [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexed_display) about multiplexed displays.

Comment: It's not a good manner to change the the parts of question answered in an answer, invalidating the answer. Now I have to remove it as it is not an answer anymore.

Comment: Im sorry i was still thinking about how to edit it as you were answering

Comment: You might want to change the title.  The CRC part of it really has little to do with your question.

Comment: __An important fact:__ While this IC can provide up to 25mA on each output, the overall current is limited to about 100mA (not sure about this value, check datasheet!). So, the PIC can drive LEDs directly, but not more than 5. You can use low-current LEDs which take 2mA only, but I haven't seen LED-bars with those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [PIC18F4550 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39632e.pdf), the following port pins are available as general purpose I/O (GPIO):

```
RA0-5:         6 GPIO pins, 4 also assigned as analog inputs 0-4
RB0-7:         8 GPIO pins, 5 also assigned as analog inputs 8-12
RC0-2, RC4-7:  7 GPIO pins
RD0-7:         8 GPIO pins
RE0-2:         3 GPIO pins, also assigned as analog inputs 5-7
```

So you could use ports B, C, and D plus one pin from port E for your 24 LEDs.  Or use less pins by implementing some sort of multiplexing scheme as suggested in the other answers.

By writing a value 0f 1010 (binary) to the PCFGx field of the ADCON1 register on startup, this will configure all of the analog inputs in both port B (8-12) and port E (5-7) to digital.  This will still leave up to five analog inputs (0-4) on port A if needed.

Each of the GPIO pins can sink or source 25 mA directly, so you won't need to have any transistor drivers for the LEDs.

Answer (score 1):

The analog inputs can be used as I/O.  I would recommend looking in to using some form of multiplexing, perhaps charlieplexing, to control that may LEDs.